# How to get three.js sprite in Verold script

Tags: javascript, three.js, verold

First post here on stack overflow...

I've been playing around with the three.js based world editor called [verold](http://www.verold.com/). It has some great features, but I've run into a problem with the scripting setup.

I'm trying to implement a THREE.Sprite() and attach it as a component of an object.

Here's what I've tried:

```
 Component.prototype.objectCreated = function() {
  // this.getThreeData() is available

   this.spriteimage.load({
    load:_.bind(function() {
    this.createImageSprite();
    }, this)
   });
 };


Component.prototype.createImageSprite = function(){

  //Load the spriteimage
  var map = this.spriteimage.threeData;
  var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: map, color: "rgb(255,0,0)", fog: true, useScreenCoordinates: false} );
  var mySprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
  mySprite.scale.set(1,1,1);
  mySprite.location.x = 0.5;
  mySprite.location.y = 0.5;
  mySprite.location.y = 0.5;

  scene.add(mySprite);
};
```

The script has an attribute called **spriteimage**, which is a verold asset -> 2D texture.

When this script is added as a component of the scene, the project runs, but you can't see a sprite at all.

I've tried replicating this code in a regular three.js project with success.

Can anybody offer a solution to this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of minor issues with your code. Otherwise, it works fine.
First, `mySprite.location` should be `mySprite.position`. Perhaps an earlier version of Three.JS used 'location'?

The second issue is the reference to 'scene' is not defined. In a script, you can call 'this.getThreeScene()' to return the reference to the THREE.Scene that the object that this script is attached to is part of.

Comment: Thanks Mike,That fixed it. Not sure why i was calling .position, I think I copied it from a previous example somewhere!